# How to fix this type inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```js
const data = {
    "a": "111",
    "b": "222"
}

for (let key in data){
    console.log(data[key]); // TypeScript error here
}
```

Error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ "a": string; "b": string; }'. 
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   '{ "a": string; "b": string; }'.

Comment: I just tried this code it runs fine. How come you're getting this error?

Comment: Looks like your code snippet works too.

Comment: @Train tried it were? it isn't really an "error" per say, it's a type mismatch that would only occur if you're running it in a typescript environment under certain circumstances.

Comment: @Train it definitely creates a typescript type error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMBEC+AXAQIwX4A0Oe+ARiQQEyv5YC+WWAZiAE4wAFABsAprADWYgJ4wAlmHhIEASmx4YoSCHEA6ESADmQxMgDa0mQF1VAbk5A

Comment: @KevinB Ok I see. I tried it in TS fiddle and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an index signature to `data`, i.e.:

```
const data: { [key: string]: string } = {
    a: '111',
    b: '222'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
console.log(data[key as keyof typeof data]);
```

Which is pretty ugly.

But it seems like you are treating `data` as a dictionary with string keys, rather than having specific properties of specific types. In which type `data` with a `string` index to be able to index it with arbitrary strings.

```
let data: { [key: string]: string } = { a: '111', b: '222' }
```